# What is the Rice Index? How does it measure party unity?

Tags: political-theory, parties, measurement

I've read that a so-called [Rice index](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2142407) is used in political science to measure party unity. There's no Wikipedia page on this notion. How exactly is it defined?

(Yes, I have jstor access and I can read that paper, but I think this question might of interest to some who can't.)

Answer (score 10):

There is a [German Wikipedia page](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rice-Index).

The Rice index measures agreement within groups on a certain issue or proposal. Given a certain issue and a group of people we write the number of people in favour F and the number of people opposed O. The Rice index is then given by (|.| is the [absolute value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_value))

> RI = | F-O | / (F+O)

This gives a number between 0 and 1 so that a higher number indicates more agreement or unity among the group. The index is zero when F=O, which happens when the party is evenly split on the issue.

As noted in [this paper](https://eml.berkeley.edu/~groland/pubs/hnrbjps.pdf), it's not always a useful measure. For example, in the European Parliament members have three voting options: *in favour*, *oppose* and *abstain*. The Rice index cannot be used for that. The paper does name another measure that does account for that: the [*Attinà index*](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/229766605_The_Voting_Behaviour_of_the_European_Parliament_Members_and_the_Problem_of_Europarties), but I cannot find a corresponding Wikipedia page for that.

Comment: @Ev.Kounis that was a typo, it should indeed be F=O, i.e. the opposing group and the group in favour are of equal size.

Comment: I was able to find a full-text of that paper [here](https://www.academia.edu/1584700/The_voting_behaviour_of_the_European_Parliament_members_and_the_problem_of_the_Europarties), it looks like the formula the author uses is: AI = (Larvest Vote Share - Sum of other Vote Shares) / Total number of Votes (X 100 to get a percentage). (I found this at what is labeled as page 564).

Answer (score 4):

In addition to JJJ's answer, the index is usually averaged across a set of votes of interest; for example across a legislative session.

> While the Rice-index is calculated for each vote, most often
>   the average value of this index is of interest.

Cf. [Hug (2006)](https://www.ethz.ch/content/dam/ethz/special-interest/gess/cis/cis-dam/CIS_DAM_2015/WorkingPapers/WP_2006/2006_WP15_Hug.pdf).

---

It's also not actually the case that the Rice index *cannot* be used if Abstain is an option (except in one extreme case as JJJ correctly notes below in a comment). The paper in question (Hix et al.) notes that:

> However, the problem with the Rice index in the European
>   Parliament is that MEPs have three voting options: Yes, No and Abstain. Attina
>   consequently developed a cohesion measure specifically for the European Parliament,
>   where the highest voting option minus the sum of the second and third options was divided
>   by the sum of all three options. But, the Attina index can produce negative scores on
>   individual votes, since a party split equally between all three voting options produces a
>   cohesion score on the Attina index of -0.333.
>
> As a result, by enabling all three voting choices to be taken into account, and by
>   producing cohesion scores on a scale from 0 to 1, our Agreement Index is an alternative
>   to the Rice and Attina indices for measuring party cohesion in the European Parliament
>   (or in any parliament with three voting options). Nevertheless, the cohesion scores
>   produced by our index can be compared to scores produced by these other two indices.
>   Our results correlate perfectly with the Attina scores, as our index is simply a rescaling
>   of the scores from 0 to 1, and correlate at the 0.98 level with the Rice scores for the same
>   data on the European Parliament. Note, however, that the difference between our scores
>   and the Rice scores are higher for parties that tend to Abstain as a block (for example, when
>   parties Abstain strategically).

So in a practical context (EU parliament), the Rice score was usually well-correlated (0.98) with the Abstention-sensitive measures. As for the formula for the latter:

Let `M = max{Y, N, A}` and let `N = Y+N+A`, then the Hix index is

`(M - 1/2 (N - M)) / N =  (3M - N) / 2N`

which is zero if the votes are equally split (1/3) among Y, N, A.

But all three (Rice, Attina ~ Hix) measures [inflate the decohesion score of small parties](https://doi.org/10.1017/S0007123405000372).

Another limitation is that these (per-party) indexes cannot be computed if the vote is secret, since per-party breakdowns of Y/N/A are not available then. This is actually the case for some types of votes in some European national parliaments. [Another criticism](http://dx.doi.org/10.1111/j.1467-9477.2012.00287.x) related to this latter point is that in systems with mixed open and secret votes

> it has often been
>   questioned if roll call behaviour is an appropriate indicator for the identification
>   of party cohesion since open votes are often asked for in situations
>   where party unity is urgently required. In other words, roll call analysis is
>   probably a better indicator for party discipline than party cohesion. Open
>   votes actually lead to higher party unity than secret votes because deviant
>   behaviour is openly manifested. Analytically, this leads to the impression
>   that party cohesion is higher than it really is. Because of this selection bias,
>   roll call analysis is not a suitable means for the analysis of party cohesion in
>   parliamentary systems ([Carrubba et al. 2006](https://doi.org/10.1017/S0007123406000366); [Hug 2010)](https://doi.org/10.1017/S0007123409990160).

Comment: Rice cannot be used if everyone voted to abstain. Not likely, but then you would get 0 in the denominator.